# System.InvalidOperationException connecting to SQLExpress database?

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= LAPTOP-KVFS4TPD\\SQLEXPRESS; Database= PayPalDB; UID= sa; PWD= 061199081298;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_DBASE", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FNtxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", MNtxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LNtxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Emailtxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email2", Email2txt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", txtDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Addresstxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreditCardNo", CCNtxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CVVNo", CVVtxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", GenderRDL.SelectedItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", DDLCountry.SelectedItem);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    Server.Transfer("UserLogIn.aspx", true);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m2hY.png)

The error is in `con.Open();`:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is wrong.

This is the correct syntax for SQLExpress connection strings:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

In your case:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PayPalDB;UID=sa;PWD=061199081298;");
```

Comment: I tried and now it has a new error. Saying "No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem to a known managed provider native type." It's pointing to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` @KobyDouek

Comment: OK, that is a new issue - please accept my answer and post this as a new question, I will answer there.

Comment: @MatthewCortez Happy to help, please post the new question URL here so I can further assist you.